# responsive div and height % does not work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've got a small problem when I am trying to make a div with a img background responsive.

1. the div doesn't get size of the image : 540px-290px
2. when I resize the browser the 2 div not resize together.

In each div I have a background image, I want the div to be responsive
but both 2 div don't get full size, i am using % for be responsive.
if i use pixels will not make responsive.

that is a image how should be my div.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfzZD.jpg

I am using bootstrap framework

html

```
  <div class="row index-banner">

    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="latest-mobile">
        <h1> releases?</h1>    
        <p>We got you </p>
        <p>Find out more ></p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6">
       <div class="sponge-bob">
        <h1>We have just ....</h1>
        <p>Let your kids enjoy .</p>
        <p>Find out more ></p>
        </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

CSS

```
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.col-xs-6 .sponge-bob {
  background: url(../../public/images/content/sponge-bob.jpg) no-repeat;
  margin-left: 5%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  display: table;
  position: relative;
}

.col-xs-6 .latest-mobile {
  background: url(../../public/images/content/latest-mobile.jpg) no-repeat center center scroll;
  margin-left: 7%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  display: table;
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Make a fiddle if you can. Easier to help!

Comment: please create fiddle or give live site link so we can help.

Answer (score 1):

This might solve your problem

```css
.latest-mobile,
.sponge-bob {
  min-height: 290px;
}
```

Comment: i got the size 290px right, the problem now is : when i resize the div the background img does not follow the size and dont stay responsive . so if i resize the div the background img start cut.

Comment: i know that, that reason i am trying do in % .

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you need to define minimum height so
Set `min-height: 100%;`